# Block access to all .php files except some specific files (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to send visitor to custom 404 error page when it tries to access to a `.php` URL, but with some specific exceptions:

Exceptions like:

```
(maybe-something/)/allowed-file.php
```

My current `.htaccess` file blocks access to all `.php` files:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

# Force WWW & SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

##.php envia a 404
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php - [F,L]
```

How can I add a few dozen of specific exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ##.php envia a 404
> RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
> RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php - [F,L]
> ```

Change this to:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/allowed-file\.php$
RewriteRule .\.php - [F]
```

The `!` prefix negates the expression. So the 2nd condition is successful when the requested URL is *not* `/allowed-file.php` or `/<anything>/allowed-file.php`. The 2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive (following the `!` prefix) is a regular expression (by default).

To add more exceptions; add more *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives).

Note that I removed the capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* since this is not being used. And the `L` flag is not required when using the `F` flag (it is implied).

However, this rule is in the wrong place in your config file. It should be immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive and *before* the canonical redirects.

Also, that stray `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80` directive (immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive) is superfluous and should be removed (to avoid accidental errors later).

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond